# Unlock FileVault encrypted drive knowing only user password

Tags: macos, encryption, filevault, apfs

I have an external disk which is clone of a MacBook internal disk. I used it as an external boot disk from time to time. Today when I tried to boot from it on a new MacBook it stopped working and I was met with a [prohibitory icon](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156#prohibitorysymbol). The disk has a pretty recent update of Mojave. On a MacBook with Apple T1 a prohibitory symbol is displayed, on a MacBook with Apple T2 it goes into recovery mode and asks for disk password.

I'm trying to mount it on a working machine now, but the disk password is not known to me. I have either chose to store it in iCloud or didn't care enough to save it.

Now I'm curios how the boot process works and whether I can mimic it to extract FileVault password. I know the account password and also all the iCloud credentials. I would guess that FileVault password is stored somewhere on PreBoot volume to which I have access and is encrypted with my account password. How could I extract it? Or, how could I check if encryption password is stored in iCloud?

Is there other alternatives to getting data off of that disk?

I have pretty recent backups, but it would be nice to decrypt it anyway.

Comment: This may be some helpful reading on the subject: https://www.macworld.com/article/3268809/how-to-find-your-filevault-recovery-key-in-macos.html

Comment: When you used this disk as an external boot disk, did you enter your account password to start up, or did you use the disk password? If you used the account password, that should also work for mounting it as a secondary drive.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson account password. It doesn't work for mounting.